# Change font size for an AlertDialog message

Tags: fonts, android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to change the font size of the `AlertDialog` message.

```
Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Application1GoodExample.this);
        builder.setMessage("Your form has been successfully submitted");
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();             
            }
        });

        builder.show();
    }
});
```

I get an error message saying that "`findViewById()`" is undefined for the type `AlertDialog.Builder`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use this :

```
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

TextView msgTxt = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);   
msgTxt.setTextSize(16.0);
```

in your case :

```
Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Application1GoodExample.this);

        builder.setMessage("Your form has been successfully submitted");
        builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();             
            }
        });

        // this will solve your error
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
        alert.getWindow().getAttributes();

        TextView textView = (TextView) alert.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        Button btn1 = alert.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        btn1.setTextSize(16);
    }
});
```

If this didn't help you, post your LogCat Error in your question.

Comment: For some reason my progam crashes when I press the submit button to display an alert dialog message

Comment: I edited my answer. Error because you use `builder.show();`.

Comment: This worked perfectly! thank you so much! I am also trying to change the size of the "Exit" button but as I'm very new to Android I cannot figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: I edited my answer to achive what you want.

Comment: How to do the same thing to the title?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
 AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setMessage("Hello world").show();
 TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
 textView.setTextSize(40);
```

Answer (score 1):

the method findViewById belongs to the type View.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Application1GoodExample.this);
builder.setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.cancel();           
    } 
});
builder.setMessage("Your form has been successfully submitted");
AlertDialog theDialog=builder.create();
TextView textView = (TextView) theDialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
textView.setTextSize(40);

theDialog.show();
```

Comment: For some reason my progam crashes when I press the submit button to display an alert dialog message

Comment: maybe if you show us the logcat output :)

Comment: I have used AwadKab's solution and managed to change the size of the Alert message without getting any errors. Do you know if I can do the same for the "Exit" button? I'm very new to Android development and cannot figure out how to do this. thank you.

Comment: if you want to customize the elements of a dialog, the best way is to create a brand new view for your dialog. Take a look at this: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using CustomDialog, i suggest you to add TextView as following,

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(android.R.id.message); // remove builder object
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. However, my program crashes when I press the Submit button. I've updated my code above.